# Is there any way to create two tables in the database for one odoo module?

Tags: python-2.7, odoo

Each module in odoo have a table in the database.

I'd like to know if I can create two tables in the odoo database for one module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, for every `class new_class(...` with a unique `_name="new.class"` is created a table in the data base, if you want more than one table, you need to create more than one class in your .py file

For more reference look the `account` module in `account_invoice.py` you have `class account_invoice(models.Model):  _name = "account.invoice"` and `class account_invoice_line(models.Model):  _name = "account.invoice.line"` for each class are a table in the data base.
I Hope this will can help you!